# Using Parallax screen

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to use parallax screen in my game code using libgdx in which screen is moving in y direction. My game code is given as...

```
   public class ParallaxLayer{
   public TextureRegion region ;
   public Vector2 parallaxRatio;
   public Vector2 startPosition;
   public Vector2 padding ;
   public ParallaxLayer(TextureRegion region,Vector2 parallaxRatio,Vector2 padding){
      this(region, parallaxRatio, new Vector2(0,0),padding);
   }

   public ParallaxLayer(TextureRegion region,Vector2 parallaxRatio,Vector2 startPosition,Vector2 padding){
      this.region  = region;
      this.parallaxRatio = parallaxRatio;
      this.startPosition = startPosition;
      this.padding = padding;
   }
}


   public class ParallaxBackground {
   private ParallaxLayer[] layers;
   private Camera camera;
   private SpriteBatch batch;
   private Vector2 speed = new Vector2();

   public ParallaxBackground(ParallaxLayer[] layers,float width,float height,Vector2 speed){
      this.layers = layers;
      this.speed.set(speed);
      camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
   }

   public void render(float delta){
    this.camera.position.add(speed.x * delta, speed.y * delta, 0);
    for(ParallaxLayer layer : layers){
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
        batch.begin();
        float currentY = - camera.position.y * layer.parallaxRatio.y % ( layer.region.getRegionHeight() + layer.padding.y) ;

        if( speed.y < 0 )
            currentY += -( layer.region.getRegionHeight() + layer.padding.y);
        do{
            float currentX = -camera.position.x * layer.parallaxRatio.x % ( layer.region.getRegionWidth() + layer.padding.x) ;
            if( speed.x < 0)
                currentX += -(layer.region.getRegionWidth() + layer.padding.x);
            do{
                batch.draw(layer.region,
                        -this.camera.viewportWidth/2 + currentX + layer.startPosition.x ,
                        -this.camera.viewportHeight/2 + currentY + layer.startPosition.y);
                currentX += ( layer.region.getRegionWidth() + layer.padding.x);
            }while(currentX < camera.viewportWidth);
            currentY += ( layer.region.getRegionHeight() + layer.padding.y);
        }while( currentY < camera.viewportHeight);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

and draw it in render method as

```
 ParallaxBackground rbg = new ParallaxBackground(new ParallaxLayer[]{
                new ParallaxLayer(bgRegion,new Vector2(),new Vector2(0, 0)),
                new ParallaxLayer(bgRegion2,new Vector2(1.0f,1.0f),new Vector2(0, 500)),
                new ParallaxLayer(bgRegion3,new Vector2(0.1f,0),new Vector2(0,480),new Vector2(0, 0)),
        }, 480, 800, new Vector2(350,0)); 
}

rbg.render(deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ParallaxBackground rbg = new ParallaxBackground(new ParallaxLayer[]{
            new ParallaxLayer(bgRegion,new Vector2(),new Vector2(0, 0)),
            new ParallaxLayer(bgRegion2,new Vector2(1.0f,1.0f),new Vector2(0, 500)),
            new ParallaxLayer(bgRegion3,new Vector2(0.1f,0),new Vector2(0,480),new Vector2(0, 0)),
    }, 480, 800, new Vector2(0,350));
```

}

if u read the documentation of this class u find that the last parameter is the relative velocity ratio and u passed 0 in y. u need to pass some other value than it

i am giving another sample of my game

```
   new ParallaxLayer(Assets.backgroundSprite, new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 200000)), 
       new ParallaxLayer(Assets.clouds, new Vector2(0, 0.05f), new Vector2(0, 440), new Vector2(0, 200000)),
        new ParallaxLayer(Assets.cloud1, new Vector2(0.4f, 0), new Vector2(240, 750), new Vector2(1000, 200000)), 
        new ParallaxLayer(Assets.cloud2, new Vector2(0.06f, 0), new Vector2(40, 600), new Vector2(500, 200000)),
        new ParallaxLayer(Assets.cloud1, new Vector2(0.5f, 0), new Vector2(700, 680), new Vector2(1500, 200000)),
```

hope it helps u out

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when I am using your code then camera position is updating with game objects position but background screen is still not moving. I want to move my background screen along y axis.

Comment: for that u need to make one more layer of  background. ideal way to do is not mobe bg. but since we cant help it so make atleast one satic layer.by static i mean with no velocity and make other layers to get feel of movement and take bg height greater than camera height. 900 for instance, instead of 800. it gives good feel