# How to render alternating sprites to achieve infinite background in Libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering, sprite

I am trying to write a program in Libgdx that has a scrolling background.
The way am trying to scroll the background is as follows:

```
//creating two sprites whose size is the 2*viewportwidth
//this shows half of the sprite on my phone screen
//which I assume that it takes two viewport widths to show the entire sprite
sprite1;
sprite2;
//setting the positions which shows the sprites next to each other
sprite1.setPosition(0f,0f);
sprite2.setPosition(2f*viewportwidth,0);
//on to my render method, I have the following besides the usual:

@Override
public void render(){
//usual stuff here
camera.update
camera.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

batch.begin();
sprite1.draw(batch);
sprite2.draw(batch);
batch.end();

moveCammy();

}

private void moveCammy(){

if(System.currentTimeMillis()-time>1000){
moviX=moviX+0.1*camera.viewportWidth;//moviX is a float
camera.translate(moviX,0f);
time= System.currentTimeMillis();

if(System.currentTimeMillis()-time2>22000){
sprite1.setX(4f*camera.viewportWidth)//since each phone screen width 
//represents half of each sprite. It takes two phone screens to show 
//one sprite. Since, originally there were two sprites it takes 4 phone 
//screens to show them side by side.However, third sprite doesn't appear 
//right after the second sprite. I think it should since it's 4 phone 
// screens away. I assume the translation of the camera is around the second
//sprite after about 220000 milliseconds. 

time2= System.currentTimeMillis();}

}
```

Everything works in the program, except that the third sprite doesn't appear 
at all. My goal is to keep alternating sprite1 and sprite2 infinitely to achieve
an infinite background.

Please advise as to what might be wrong.

Comment: Can you post actual code from your project? There are missing closing brackets and semicolons, and nonexistent methods called (`camera.setProjectionMatrix` for example) which makes it hard to see what your error is. It looks sort of like you are moving your camera only once per second and it is accelerating. And why are you basing your sprite movement on time instead of on camera position?

Comment: read follwing question i think it may help ypu idea is to use a parralax in LIBGDX  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172006/using-parallax-screen/18172144#18172144